# Pass NSString between two DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

**MasterViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailViewControllerSeque"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailView = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        theList = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        detailView.theList = theList;

        // String to pass to DetailViewController
        detailView.string2pass = @"this is a passing string";
    }
}
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
NSString *string2pass;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *string2pass;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
NSLog(@"%@", string2pass);
```

**Output: (null)**



What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you call the NSLog from?

Comment: Did u synthasize that property? Once u can print the NSLog for detailView.string2pass before assigning..

Comment: I think this is more detailed try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: Yes, i corrected it in my question

Comment: Are you sure detailView is not nil? NSLog(@"%@", detailView) after you get it from the segue.

Comment: are u sure theList is string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have this in your implementation, it won't work as you expected.

```
@synthesize string2pass = string2pass;
```

..or you can fix it by deleting the line:

```
NSString *string2pass;
```

Your log is logging the value of string2pass variable you declared. But there is another variable _string2pass.

```
NSLog(@"%@", string2pass);
```

The @property you declared, is backed by a variable name _string2pass if you don't explicitly write a @synthesize statement. Not writing an @sythesize statement is the same as declaring one like so:

```
@synthesize string2pass = _string2pass;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but even when I remove `NSString *string2pass;` and I add `@synthesize string2pass = _string2pass;` I´m still getting (null) :(

Comment: You don't actually need to explicitly write that synthesize statement if you don't want, it's no harm it being there - but if you don't write it, it is created for you. If you did that, then you probably won't compile now without changing your NSLog statement to read NSLog(@"%@", self.string2pass).... have you done this? Also, where are you calling the NSLog statement from?

Comment: Called from viewDidLoad. Yes, I also tried it w/o @sythesize and self.string2pass, but also not working...

Comment: I don't use story boards, so I'm not too sure on the lifecycle - is viewDidLoad called before you have set the variable? What if you log from viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.string2pass` in `NSLog`. When we use self. to access a property then the getter/setter is called.

Comment: please give the reason for downvoting?

Comment: ...it wasn't me... however, I think you were down voted because your answer hides the real problem that there are 2 variables, which could lead to more bugs/confusion later down the line.

Comment: Yeah I agree that it does not include the whole scenario but it is not a wrong answer. Anyways you have answered it completely above so it does not make any sense to repeat those things again.

Comment: Technically, you are correct. I don't think it deserves the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `NSString` property to your `SecondViewController.h` file:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
```

and then in `FirstViewController.m` file create `SecondViewController` object and pass to it whatever string you want:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewcontroller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ACEViewController" bundle:nil];
secondViewcontroller.myString = @"WhateverYouNeedToPass";
```

Log string in `SecondViewController`

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **DetailViewController.h** only you need to define this -

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *string2pass;
```

In your **DetailViewController.m**

```
@synthesize string2pass
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Still getting (null) :(